# Is there something like Qnotero for Mendeley?

Tags: software, reference-managers

I've been using Zotero for bibliography, citation and reference management for a long time. Particularly, I came to love Qnotero, which is a stand-alone application, providing a handy way of accessing PDFs from the Zotero library even when Zotero isn't running: One just presses a customizable hotkey, a popup appears on the desktop, where you enter a search term (e.g., title or author of a paper), hit enter, and the PDF opens. However, I recently discovered Mendeley, and it's really appealing to me. Still, I'm missing the Qnotero functionality. Is there something similar to Qnotero available for Mendeley?

Comment: Mendeley isn't open source like Zotero is (although I do believe it has a developer API). That may make it harder to develop such functionality for third parties.